# Shaped objects positioned in a reference frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames

If I have a shaped object (not a point) in a fixed 3-dim reference frame, I believe it takes 6 "pieces of information" to position it: $X, Y, Z$, and three orientation angles.  If I add another shaped object to the reference frame and want to describe its position relative to the first object, I believe it should take 6 more pieces of information to accomplish this: $\delta X, \delta Y, \delta Z$, and three $\delta$ angles for orientation.  Each new object added increases the "system information" by 6.  Am I thinking about this correctly and can you point me to where I can learn more about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Of course, if your object has some symmetries, you might be able to get away with less than six numbers. If it is some kind of straight stick (cilindrical symmetry) you just need 5 numbers. If it is a sphere/point (spherical symmetry), only 3.

To learn more about this, you may start reading the wikipedia page on [Degrees of freedom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom)